# CSS3 Dropdown Transition On Click

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, css-transitions

I'm tring to make a simple drop down when going into mobile view so that my div understands a click to drop down the info box.

Here's what my HTML looks like:

```
                <div class="ben-item col-md-3 col-xs-6">
                    <div class="ben-item-cover text-center">
                         <h3>Some text</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ben-item-content text-center">
                         <p>A drop down div which shows this description</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="ben-item col-md-3 col-xs-6">
                    <div class="ben-item-cover text-center">
                         <h3>Some text</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ben-item-content text-center">
                         <p>A drop down div which shows this description</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
@media (max-width:480px){
.ben-item{width:100%;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;height:auto;margin-bottom:5px;overflow:visible}
.ben-item .ben-item-cover{padding:0;height:50px;line-height:50px;cursor:pointer}
.ben-item .ben-item-cover i {font-size:16px;float:left;margin:0 0 0 15px;line-height:50px}
.ben-item .ben-item-cover h3{margin:0 0 0 10px;font-size:19px;line-height:50px;float:left}
.ben-item .ben-item-content{height:0;padding:0 15px;overflow:hidden}
.ben-item .ben-item-content h3{margin-top:40px}
.ben-item .ben-item-content p{font-size:16px}
.ben-item.active>.ben-item-content,.ben-item.active>.ben-item-cover,.ben-item:hover>.ben-item-content,.ben-item:hover>.ben-item-cover{-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);transform:translate3d(0,0,0)}
.ben-item.active>.ben-item-content{height:234px}
}
```

My other transitions work fine, I just can't work out why this isn't working, greatful for any help.

Comment: wheres the "click" js

Comment: I used a transition on my other divs on hover and that worked fine without js. Do I definitely need JS for this?

Comment: I mean you mention "click"

Comment: But won't the click js apply to the div when it's not in mobile view? I only want it to work in max-width:480px

Comment: I believe you would need JS to perform a dropdown menu, at least it would be much easier.

Comment: Yeah I have done, thanks guys, ended up using JQuery toggle to switch between the active and hidden states. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended up using JQuery toggle to switch between the active and hidden states. Works perfectly.

Thanks for the advice!